# Removing cookie on logout causing Server status code 400 netcore 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, post, razor

I am attempting to remove the session cookie on logout, resulting in a 400 error.

```
LoginPartial.cshtml


@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <form method="post" class="form-inline" asp-page="/Logout">
        <button id="Button" type="submit" name="submit" formmethod="post" class="btn">Logout</button>
    </form>
}else
{
    <a class="btn btn-link" asp-page="/Login">Login</a>
}
```

and the Logout.cshtml.cs looks like this:

```
    namespace WebApp.Pages
{
    public class LogoutModel : PageModel
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(){
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("MyCookieAuth");
            return RedirectToPage("../");
        }

    }
}
```

The Cookies and claims all work well, as well as the User Identify Authentication.
(net6.0)

Answer (score 0):

the Logout.cshtml.cs looks like this:

```
    namespace WebApp.Pages
{
    public class LogoutModel : PageModel
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(){
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Remove("MyCookieAuth");
            return RedirectToPage("../");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this change results in the following error: '''error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of 'CollectionExtensions.Remove<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, TKey, out TValue)'''